# WPF - hide element when hovering a mouse over another element

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers

There are some elements in a grid, and all I want is to show/hide the button when a mouse is over a rectangle.

```xaml
<UserControl ...>
    <Grid>
        <Rectangle ...>
        <Button ...>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I've tried several triggers but was unsuccessful so far. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what you need:
A datatrigger bound to the Control that should trigger the hiding.
alternativly you could use a converter sth like a `BoolenToInvisibilityConverter`

Ps if you want to invert the logic you need to set the visibility in the style as it would be overwritten otherwise

```
            <StackPanel>
                <Rectangle Fill="Red" Height="20" Width="29" Name="MyRect"/>
                <Button>
                    <Button.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="Button">
                        <!--<Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>-->
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=MyRect, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Button.Style>                    
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
```

the trigger-landscape in Wpf can be confusing sometimes, dont worry you will learn to live with it!

Comment: It works contrarywise - when mouse is over a button, rectangle becomes invisible. But It should show/hide the button when over a rectangle :)

Comment: thanks, but it has the same problem as Mathivanan's version.

Comment: i edited once again check out the line that is comented out
just comment it back in and change the `Setter` from `Hidden` to `Visibile`

Comment: You are creating a style. Styles can always be overwritten in your XAML. Imagine a button-style you created that makes all buttons red. If you define one button to be blue it will still be blue as you have overwritten its color. Thats exactly what happens if you set the visibility directly on the element. It will overwrite your style so the parameter needs to be set in the style as well (see answer--> comment)

Comment: thanks for the explanation and update :) works just fine!